# Why are that one line of paragraph not following the others by aligning with them

Tags: html, css

So I want this paragraph of "**Numbers of hours you work with pc**" to align under and between the labels and input type= text of **studentnumber:** and **games:**

it is way out of position as you can see, how can I fix this?

```css
.container {
    background-color: rgb(157, 230, 255);
    height: 600px;
}

.container input {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}

.container label {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 20px;

}

form {
    text-align: left;
    

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <form>           
            <div style="line-height: 400%;">
                <br>
            </div>
            
            <label for="studentnumber">Studentnumber:</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <p>Numbers of hours you work with pc with</p>
            <br>
            <label for="games">Games:</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <label for="sosial media">Sosial media:</label>
            <input type="text">
            <br>
            <label for="skole">School:</label>
            <input type="text">    
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: did you try `clear: both;` on the `<p>` ?

Comment: yes that worked out, thanks @Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `<label>` and `<input>` elements are floating `float: left;` you need to suppress the floating effect for the text.

Therefore, applying a `clear: both;` (or just `clear: left;`) on the `<p>` element will force it to wrap to a new line.